# Clicking a button to trigger a delayed click for another buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a button that when it's being a click, it will trigger a click for another button too but with a delay for each of them. For example, if the `Main Button` is clicked, the `Sub Button 1` will trigger a click, then `Sub Button 2` will be clicked after 2 seconds and the `Sub Button 3` will be clicked after 4 seconds.

The real scenario is a customer can select up to 3 products, the 3 products will be added to a cart if they click the `main button` because the `add to cart button` of those 3 products will be clicked too as they click the main button. The products page has an Ajax. If I click the main button, sometimes only 1 or 2 product(s) are being added. I'm trying to delay a click for each button.

```js
$(".main-button").on("click",function(){
 $(".container .row").each(function(i){
  $rowNum = $(this).attr("id","row-" + i);
  $rowNum.find("button").trigger("click").delay(5000).text("clicked");
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="main-button">Main Button</button>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <button class="sub-button">Sub Button 1</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button class="sub-button">Sub Button 2</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button class="sub-button">Sub Button 3</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you tirgger the functions behind the buttons instead of the buttons themself? that way you wouldnt need the delay

Comment: @Erch I don't know how to do it yet (need learn Ajax and so on). I'll figure out that later. I'm trying use this solution to make it work for now. Also need to learn how to delay the button clicks.

Comment: bad idea imao, just learn about it now, the time you waste looking for a work around you could use to do it the right way, and when you are at it take a look at the event loop of browsers, then you know why your code doesnt work atm too

Comment: @Erch This a solution I've come up for now. But for sure I will try to learn it and take your advice since I don't have a choice too.

Comment: @Erch By the way thanks in advance if you could help me how to delay the button clicks.

Comment: since i am not found of workarounds I cant help you but this will help you understand the reason your former code aint working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Referring to the past comments, it would be a way better practice to simply call the functions themselves instead of making automated button clicks. It will make the code more clean, and it will make it easier for you to look back on, and doesn't look like a "hack". All you need to do is to check if the functions are reachable within the scope of the main button function and call them inside that. AJAX has integrated *success* functions in which you can place the other functions to be called upon success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".main-button").on("click",function(){
   myLoop ($(".container .row").children().length)
});


var i = 1;                    

function myLoop (count) {          
  setTimeout(function () {    
    $('.container :nth-child('+i+')').children('button').text("clicked")               
      if (i < count) {            
      i++
         myLoop(count);            

      }                       
   }, 1000)
}
```

Try demo - 
https://jsfiddle.net/jijomonkmgm/oL3bzp5r/

Comment: i tried, it delayed the click for 5 seconds but all of them are being clicked at the same time. It should have delayed click one after another.

Comment: it gave the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *specifically* what you asked for, but the outcome of the functionality that you seek will be the same.

In the comments, others and myself, talked about how you could choose to call your sub button functions within the main function itself, without having the logic of a chained button clicking functionality.

Before you can do that, you need to make sure that all of your sub functions are within the *global scope* so that you can access them in your main function.

Example:

```
subButtonOneFunction() {
    //do something
}

subButtonTwoFunction() {
    //do something
}

subButtonThreeFunction() {
    //do something
}

$(".main-button").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/your_page.php',
        data: {
            data : dataVar,
            moreData : moreDataVar
        },
        success: function (html) {
            subButtonOneFunction();
            subButtonTwoFunction();
            subButtonThreeFunction();
            //and so forth
        }
    })
});
```

The sub button functions in this example is within reach of the main function, and so you will be able to call the sub functions within the main function.

Not knowing if there is more to your main function, other than the delayed, button clicking loop that you were attempting, I tried to provide an example of how an AJAX function works, plus adding a success function where you can call your sub functions.

Firstly, we declare the `type`. The type is the data type for the data the AJAX function will parse. Notable data types are `POST` and `GET`.

Secondly, we declare the `url`. The url is the page where your data will be parsed to. It can be your current page, or another page entirely.

Thirdly, we declare our variable names for our data that we wish to parse, and what their content is. The variables go by the same logic as any other variables that you know from JavaScript. So they can contain numbers, strings, arrays, whatever you normally know.

Taking one of the data variables from the AJAX example and giving it a value could be done like this:

Our AJAX example: `data : dataVar`

Literal example: `data : $('input#SomeInputContainingValue').val()`

our AJAX variable *data* will now contain the value of an input field that has the id *SomeInputContainingValue*.

Another example using the clicked elements value: `data : $(this).val()`

As you can see, the data is simply variables that you would declare as any other JavaScript variable. The difference here is that `:` is basically the syntax for `=` in the AJAX function's data array.

Lastly, we declare our `success` function in the AJAX function. What this does, is that it allows us to "do something" upon success. This is where you can call your sub functions for instance.

This would be a much cleaner approach, and will be much easier to look through when going over the application in the future, and doesn't look like a "hack" or other workarounds.

Comment: I didn't expect to received this answer with a very detailed information. This should not be wasted. I'm so excited to try it.

Comment: Note that the JavaScript notation in my example i jQuery, so you will need a jquery library.